# What do you call a distribution where most of the data points are at the minimum or maximum of the possible space?

Tags: distributions

See question in title. Note that the distribution does not has to be symmetric.

An example is:
[image]

Comment: "U-shaped" is a common term.

Comment: Hmm, I was looking for a more formal term.

Comment: _U-shaped_ may not sound 'formal', but it is widely used. _Bi-modal_ may also be appropriate. // Beta distributions with both shape parameters less than 1 are U-shaped, but the maximum values of the density function in the two tails occurs _exactly at_ the ends of the interval of support. Perhaps see red density function at top right on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Comment: U-shaped as a term seems to go back to Edgeworth and it's as good as any here. (J-shaped I never could buy.)

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining simple characterizations of the shape of a distribution was the purpose of Galtung's AJUS system proposed in [Galtung (1969)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0231030886) and implemented, for instance, in the [R agrmt package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/agrmt/agrmt.pdf). As summarized [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution), the original version of AJUS has the following characterizations:

> - A: unimodal distribution – peak in the middle
> - J: unimodal – peak at either end
> - U: bimodal – peaks at both ends
> - S: bimodal or multimodal – multiple peaks

So what you describe is an AJUS type "U" distribution. Or just a ["U-shaped distribution"](https://dictionary.apa.org/u-shaped-distribution), as @whuber says in the comments.